# Citrix NetScaler: Configure LDAP Authentication Server

Tags: ldap, citrix

I am trying to configure a Citrix NetScaler to do authentication with Active Directory, and trying to do so from the CLI.  Looking at support forums and documentation, it looks like this can be achieved by running the following commands:

```
>add authentication ldapaction ldap_Server
-serverip 10.3.255.157
-ldapBase "DC=citrix,DC=com"
-ldapBindDn user@citrix.com
-ldapBindDnPassword ..dd2604527edf70
-ldapLoginName sAMAccountName -groupAttrName "memberOf "
```

However, I cannot figure out where to get the password hash from, or how to generate it, or even what algorithm it is in.  My question for the experts is, how can I generate an appropriate hash from a given password so I can do this configuration from the CLI?  Thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make that input via GUI and the password will turn up in that encrypted form. Or input via CLI and just use plain text.

## Background

That example is from [CTX108876](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX108876) and it's not great. Background is lacking.

If for any config command you use the `-encrypted` parameter, then the systemwide encryption key is used. (This is declared on a line by itself with the [`set ns encryption` command](http://docs.citrix.com/en-us/netscaler/11/reference/netscaler-command-reference/ns/ns-encryptionparams.html).)

I don't know of a way to enter the hexstring-ified passwords on the CLI. (And I also don't know how the `set ns encryption` line is stored. I think just [some sort of obfuscation.](https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/347565-how-are-accounts-passwords-being-stored-on-a-netscaler-mpx/))

Otherwise [if you leave out the `-encrypted` parameter, it's just in plaintext](https://archive.is/u76jU#selection-1635.136-1635.164).

So either they forgot to put the `-encrypted` parameter in that example, or that weird hexstring is just the verbatim cleartext password. My money is on the first option.